# How to search on object lookup on custom field

Tags: administration, lookup, configuration, search, lookup-filter

I have a lookup field that displays the standard "name" field (renamed to Service ID) of a lookup object. However, this "Service ID" field stores the autonumberID of the object record and is not intuitive for searching against. Rather, there is also a custom field on the object called "Site Name" which would be far more intuitive to search on.

How would I configure Salesforce so that when I edit the object record and click the search icon on the lookup field I can type in a value and it will search the "site name" field rather than the "Service ID" field.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to activate a feature called **Enhanced lookup**. For that do the following steps:

- go to Setup -> Customize -> Search -> Search Settings
- Over there scroll down to the **Lookup Settings** and activate it for the wished custom object 
  [image]
- now you will be able to search in all searchable fields 
    [image]

Here is some more official information about [Enhanced Lookups](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_enhanced_lookup_enable.htm&language=en_US).